# How should I do AABB::contains?

Tags: aabb

Should an AABB "contain" a point when the point is:

- Exclusive: Only exactly inside the aabb
- Inclusive: Inside the aabb or exactly on the sides
- Almost:  Inside the aabb or a little bit outside of the sides

[image: eaabbe]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ultimately, it comes down to what you commonly check. To bring up a 4th alternative, I've used half-open intervals, so points belong to exactly one bounding box at a tight boundary.

```
bb.minX <= point.x < bb.maxX
```

Answer (score 1):

Inclusive, because when setting up containing boxes, if an object passes over the line it will be checked twice where your other methods would, and could easily not check a collision, or check too many and do a lot of extra work.