# Check if point lies within coordinates

Tags: java, 3d, lwjgl

Let's say I have min (0,0,0) and max (1,1,1).
If I have 3 points, lets say

- a (0.2,0.4,0.2)
- b (-0.5,0.8,0.2)
- c (2,0.3,0.1)

How would I go about calculating it those points are within the coordinates of min and max?

*Note that I am using simple shapes such as Cubes and that I am going to use this for optimizations with octrees*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what we call an axis aligned bounding box (AABB) containment check:

```
bool IsInsideAABB(Point check, Point min, Point max) {
    return min.x <= check.x && check.x <= max.x
        && min.y <= check.y && check.y <= max.y
        && min.z <= check.z && check.z <= max.z;      
}
```

Depending on your application, you might want to count points exactly on one boundary or another to be outside the box - so you may want to replace some of the `<=` with `<`

See [How should I do AABB::contains?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/31965/39518) for more on that.